# Remove Richfaces popup when is set to readonly

Tags: richfaces, seam

I want to render a richfaces calendar in readonly mode, when I use the readonly attribute it works, but is still displaying the calendar when clicking on the text input. I've been looking but I didn't find any property to disable this behaviour, with the popup attribute set to false the calendar is displayed all the time, and I also want to avoid this...

Is there any property (or combination of them) that basically allows the calendar to become a label?

Oh, I'd like to avoid using the disabled property

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if such attribute exists but you should be able to achieve this by using a custom calendar model and disable all days for selection in the custom model

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max, but I really don't want to show any calendar, just a readonly input with the date, and no popup or any other feature

Comment: Then you don't really need a calendar, you can just use a regular input field, read only

Comment: Yeah, but I had a panel I reuse a lot, so I was trying to make it as clean as possible

Answer (score 1):

I would use the rendered attribute and a textfield with the reversed rendered flag set. With seam you can easily format the displayed string.

Another solution could be to capture the mouseclick if readonly and consume it. This way the popup will not get the event.